# Discord.js validationerror expectedconstrainterror while using r34 api

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I`m trying to add r34 API into this bot however these error are mess, it says its not similar URL but they are. i was looking for answers and solution on internet but couldn't find accurate solution. I look forward for all the advice and help I'll be receiving. Thank you in advance

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder,EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const r34API = require('r34.api');

module.exports = {
   data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
   .setName('test')
   .setDescription('wharever')
   .addStringOption(option => option.setName("test").setDescription('YURI')),
   async execute(interaction){
       let image = await r34API.rule34(['pussy','lesbian'])
       const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
       .setTitle('here')
       .setDescription('i tried :<')
       .setColor('black')
       .setURL(`${image}`)
       .setTimestamp(Date.now())
       await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
   },
};```

[error][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ97P.png

**CombinedError (2)
 Received one or more errors

 1 ValidationError > s.nullish
 |   Expected undefined or null
 | 
 |   Received:
 |   | '"https://api-cdn.rule34.xxx/images/7213/7cf8cc1938983bbd131e4af92246bd14.png" '

 2 ExpectedConstraintError > s.string.url
 |   Invalid URL
 |
 |   Expected: expected to match an URL
 |
 |   Received:
 |   | '"https://api-cdn.rule34.xxx/images/7213/7cf8cc1938983bbd131e4af92246bd14.png" ' 

   at UnionValidator.handle (C:\VS code\Files\Discord Taihou bot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1088:23)
   at UnionValidator.parse (C:\VS code\Files\Discord Taihou bot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:201:88)
   at EmbedBuilder.setURL (C:\VS code\Files\Discord Taihou bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:272:18)
   at Object.execute (C:\VS code\Files\Discord Taihou bot\commands\randomtest.js:15:10) 
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)        
   at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\VS code\Files\Discord Taihou bot\index.js:44:5)**
````